# SQL Combine between 2 select with condition

Tags: mysql

it is possible to combine 2 select query with different where condition? here's my code

First query

```
SELECT user_pemilik_nip, FLOOR(COUNT(id) / 2) as total_terima 
FROM data_berkas 
WHERE status = 'terima' 
GROUP BY user_pemilik_nip
```

Second query

```
SELECT user_penerima_nip, FLOOR(COUNT(id) / 2) as total_menunggu 
FROM data_berkas 
WHERE status = 'menunggu' 
GROUP BY user_penerima_nip
```

data_berkas table

| id | status | user_pemilik_nip | user_penerima_nip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | terima | admin |  |
| 2 | terima | admin |  |
| 3 | menunggu | admin | staff |
| 4 | terima | staff |  |
| 5 | menunggu | staff | admin |

I've try using inner/left/right join but i can use 1 condition only, and for the result my expectation is `user_nip (user_pemilik_nip and user_penerima_nip), total_terima, total_menunggu)` and grouped by user_nip Thanks

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, i'll upload the table structure

Comment: What exactly do you expect the combined query to return?

Comment: Not sure what's your expected result, but according to the title of your question, you need `UNION`.

Comment: please provide your expected result. Combine this given query by using UNION ALL. But anything other this so need expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine two queries in one so that using conditional group by.

```
-- MySQL
SELECT CASE WHEN status = 'terima'
               THEN user_pemilik_nip
            ELSE user_penerima_nip
       END user      
     , FLOOR(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'terima' THEN id END) /2) as total_terima 
     , FLOOR(COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 'menunggu' THEN id END) /2) as total_menunggu
FROM data_berkas 
WHERE status IN ('terima', 'menunggu') 
GROUP BY CASE WHEN status = 'terima'
               THEN user_pemilik_nip
            ELSE user_penerima_nip
       END
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c088d5645dac36def7033d9c3c3b36d5

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT total.user, terima.total_terima, menunggu.total_menunggu
-- gather complete users list
FROM ( SELECT user_pemilik_nip AS user
       FROM data_berkas
       UNION 
       SELECT user_penerima_nip 
       FROM data_berkas ) AS total
-- join "terima" amounts
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user_pemilik_nip, FLOOR(COUNT(id) / 2) as total_terima 
            FROM data_berkas 
            WHERE status = 'terima' 
            GROUP BY user_pemilik_nip ) AS terima ON total.user = terima.user_pemilik_nip
-- join "menunggu" amounts
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT user_penerima_nip, FLOOR(COUNT(id) / 2) as total_menunggu 
            FROM data_berkas 
            WHERE status = 'menunggu' 
            GROUP BY user_penerima_nip ) AS menunggu ON total.user = menunggu.user_penerima_nip
```